# Want to apply If condition on basis of login ID

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysqli

I want to make `IF` `Else` Condition on the basis of User Login ID for their edit or delete Option.

```
<?php
    $ask_filter['Ask_Id']=$userlogined;
    if($user_id="$userlogined"){

        <div class="query_edit fl"><a href="queryedit.php?ID=<?=$ask_filter['Ask_Id']?>">EDIT</a></div>

    }else{}
?>
```

I apply this query but its not working.

Comment: What do you want to show for edit and delete options? Please specify that first.

Comment: thing to consider:- from where you get this `$user_id`?  And  instead of `$user_id="$userlogined"` use `$user_id==$userlogined`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$ask_filter['Ask_Id']=$userlogined;
if($user_id == $userlogined){

    <div class="query_edit fl"><a href="queryedit.php?ID=<?=$ask_filter['Ask_Id']?>">EDIT</a></div>

}else{}
```

?>

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You used a single equal sign, thereby assigning your variable instead of testing for equality.

Always use `==`in `If... Else`structures.

To be sure not to miss this error it's a good practice to put the constant as first element of your test : `If ("login" == $variable)` 
This way your code will generate an error, as it is impossible to assign a constant.

This good practice works for nearly all languages, it will even cause compilation error in compiled languages.

Comment: I want to give edit permission as per the user login person's ID Where only  the person can edit who posted any comment else no other person can edit So, Like that I want to make this If Else Condition.      <?php
$ask_filter['Ask_Id']=$userlogined;
if($user_id == $userlogined){
<div class="query_edit fl"><a href="queryedit.php?ID=<?=$ask_filter['Ask_Id']?>">EDIT</a></div>
}else{}

Comment: @RoshanKumar haven't you inverted the first part in your code?     <?php
$userlogined = $ask_filter['Ask_Id'];
if($user_id == $userlogined){
<div class="query_edit fl"><a href="queryedit.php?ID=<?=$ask_filter['Ask_Id']?>">EDIT</a></div>
}else{}

Comment: Hey Thanks It's solved..

Comment: Nice to hear, Don't hesitate to accept my answer to close your question